# preferred way to send email, httpHandler or web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I am using ASP NET 4.0
what is the preferred way to send email through `HttpHandler` Or `web service`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a bad idea as also suggested by @peer. Reminding passwords (a sensitive operation) should be securely thought and implemented (mind you, I am not even mentioning hashing them)

I guess what you are trying to achieve is to let user know that an email has been sent to them without the page is being refreshed after they submit their email right? If so, you can send the email through web service to your server side code that processes your code and send the password to your email address. You can then let that function to return true or false to let user know "an email has been sent containing your password" or "no such email found in our system."

### UPDATE

say you have a `RemindPassword.aspx` as follows;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 data: "{'email':'" + $('#txtEmail').val() + "'}",
 url: 'RemindPassword.aspx/sendEmail',
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 success: function (msg) {
  isok = JSON.parse(msg.d);
      msgelem = $('#results');
      if (isok == true) {
        msgelem.html('your password has been sent to your email.')
      } else {
        msgelem.html('this email address does not exist in our system.')
      }
 }
})
   };
});

</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Send password.."/>
<span id="results"></span>
```

in RemindPassword.aspx.vb :

Imports System.Web.Services

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function SendMail(email As String) As Boolean
    ' write code here to check if email exists.
    ' if it does, run code (or another function) to send the password.
    ' then return true
    ' if the email doesnt exist, then return false.
End Sub
```

Comment: just one small thing .
when you say server side its not the same as WebServiceName.cs?

Comment: you can call a webservice from codebehind of your page.. I am a vb guy so you'll have to figure out the c# version but, I am updating my answer in a minute to show you what I really mean..

Comment: what I want to know is if I have two files :  .ashx OR .asmx and its .cs .
and if I will call from the client to the cs file I am exposing my server side API (handler.cs/webservice.cs) ?
or any way the handler.cs and webservice.cs are exposed from their definition

Comment: ok use my sample.. web services are not designed to send passwords flying in the air.

Comment: can you explain in few words why it different if I will send the ajax request to webservice.cs and it will make the checking with the DB and send the mail and response?Thanks.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand what you mean exactly.

Comment: what I meant is when you create web service you get 2 files one is the server side webservice.cs and one is the webservice.asmx.
so why do I nedd to send the email to RemindPassword.aspx/sendEmail like you mention instead of directly to webservice.cs/sendEmail?

Comment: becasue a web service is exposed to anyone online. It's purpose is to let other websites/people to consume them.. E.g. a weather forecast. And you probably don't want people or other machines to consume your web service by attacks.

Answer (score 2):

You should send your email on your server side code. If you expose the mail api through a HttpHandler or web service your system will be used as relay server by spammers.

Comment: I need it to send the password in case the user forgot it.
so I want the user enter his mail and I will send it thru the web service or the http handler on the server side. is it bad idea?

Comment: you should of really said that this is to send a password as it has had quite an impact on the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use webservice for transfer messages but you willnot pass any credentials. you can call websercice from javascript. If you need the code I can help.

The body, cc, bcc, subject all those details can be passed to the webmethod using javascript. All other credentials should be kept inside your server code.

```
    function SendMail(txtTo, txtFrom, txtCC, txtBCC, txtSubject, txtMessage)

 {     


     // call server side method

     PageMethods.sendmail(txtTo, txtFrom, txtCC, txtBCC, txtSubject, txtMessage);

 }



 // set the destination textbox value with the ContactName

 function CallSuccess(res)

 {     

         alert(res) ;
 }



 // alert message on some failure

 function CallFailed(res)

 {

     alert(res.get_message());

 }
```

on the server

```
public static void SendMail(string txtTo, string txtFrom, string txtCC, string txtBCC, string txtSubject, string txtMessage)
{
try
    {

        //Creating the Mail Message object.
        MailMessage Email=new MailMessage();
        //Storing the To value in the object reference.
        Email.To=txtTo;                
        //Storing the From value in the object reference.
        Email.From=txtFrom;
        //Storing the CC value in the object reference.
        Email.Cc=txtCC;
        //Storing the BCC value in the object reference.
        Email.Bcc=txtBCC;
        //Storing the Subject value in the object reference.
        Email.Subject=txtSubject;
        //Specifies the email body.
        Email.Body=txtMessage;
        //Setting priority to the mail as high,low,or normal
        Email.Priority=MailPriority.High;
        //Formatting the mail as html or text.
        Email.BodyFormat=MailFormat.Text;
        //Checking whether the attachment is needed or not.
        //if(rbtnAttach)
        //{
        //    //Adding attachment to the mail.
        //    Email.Attachments.Add(
        //        new MailAttachment(FileBrowse));
        //}
        //specifying the real SMTP Mail Server.
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer.Insert(0,"127.0.0.1");
        SmtpMail.Send(Email);//Sending the mail.
        //calling the reset method to erase all the data 
        //after sending the mail.

    }
    //Catching Exception 
    catch(Exception exc)
    { 

    }

}
```

For more details, you can refer to:

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Techblaster/Techblaster_demo.zip